# Printing an ArrayList of Integers top to bottom and returning each element as a String

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

I've created a function to print values from an ArrayList and it works, however, it prints them left to right and I want them to be printed top to bottom.

My method for doing this is here:

```
ArrayList<Integer> scoresFromRounds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public String printSortedScoreList()
    {
        sortScoreList();
        String scores = scoresFromRounds.toString();
        return scores;
    }
```

I've looked around and this kind of thing seems to be working for others:

```
for (Object o : exes)
    System.out.println(o);
```

However, when I tried to do it like

```
for (Integer score : scoresFromRounds)
{

}
```

I'm not entirely sure what to put in the body of the for each, as I need this function to return a String as I then use it to display the scores within a label, and labels only accept Strings.

Does anyone have any idea on how I could achieve this?

Thanks

Edit:

By top to bottom, I mean something like

```
10

20

30

40

50
```

Comment: What do you mean by left to right ? and top to Bottom ? do you mean line by line ?
Can you also give us some type? I suppose it's an arraylist<Integer> ?

Comment: @user43968 Yeah line by line, I've added an example to the post, and yeah it's ``ArrayList<Integer>`` added that in also

Comment: I don't understand, you want to print it top to bottom ? or you want to create label ? or convert integer to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for

```
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
String newLine = "\n";
for (Integer integer : scoresFromRounds) {
    response.append(integer);
    response.append(newLine);
}
return respone;
```

This will print the result top to bottom

Comment: @Kappa123 In above solution you should use StringBuilder to concat the string instead of + operator while doing string concat in loop..

Comment: Or short: `return String.join("\n", scoresFromRounds);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but maybe the line you are looking for is some variation of

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(score));
```

Edit: if you want to have the String elsewhere, then do:

`String x = Integer.toString(score);`    System.out.println(x);

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Java Stream API version of the solution.

```java
public String print(Collection<Integer> collection) {
    return collection.stream()
            .map(Object::toString) // convert integers to strings
            .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())); // join them
}
```